# NODE AWS S3 file location is not the same as the response for certain characters

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a node app that uploads files to AWS S3 storage using their SDK.

I have a file called: `File-type (14).csv`

I upload it as follows:

```js
const AWS = require(`aws-sdk`)

const params = {
    Bucket: `MY_BUCKET`,
    Key: `path/File-type (4).csv`, 
    Body: fileContent
}
// Upload
new AWS.S3({/* config */})
.upload(params, (err, response) => {
   const location = response.Location
})
```

I then use the `location` constant to store it in my database. But the link doesn't work, when I go to AWS control panel to check, it gives it a different link.

```
From location: https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/path/File-type%20%281%29.csv
From AWS:      https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/path/File-type%2520%25281%2529.csv
```

*Please note the difference in the names after `File-type`*

I've tried `encodeURI` on the string (pre-upload, on `params.Key`) but that doesn't remove the `()` and so still creates an error. I could do a regex to remove all non-alpha-numeric values but that feels hacky, or is that the only solution, or am I missing something?

Comment: You shouldn't keep encoding it... you should _decode_ it: the first url is an encoding of: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/path/File-type (1).csv` and the second url is an encoding of the first url!

Comment: Also, I recommend on reading: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear that I tried encoding BEFORE I upload, so on `params.Key` and not the `response.Location`.

Comment: I've checked the docs posted, still doesn't explain why the `response.Location` and the actual location is not the same, they say that `()` are safe characters.

Comment: You also have space in the filename and space is a special character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS SDK has character rules to abide by. They won't tell you or fix the issue and provide the wrong link.

Before you upload you need to clean your path to avoid the "not-accepted" characters, which can be found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html

So make sure you clean your path before uploading.

Comment: A bigger point here is the false equivalence between the Amazon S3 namespace and your local file system (presumably NTFS on Windows or APFS on Mac). If you want to retain the original filenames while stored in S3 then you should either encode them safely or generate an opaque key for an object while in S3, and maintain a mapping between that S3-safe key and the original filename (e.g. in a key/value store).